# Entity Framework Deadlocks and Concurrency

Tags: .net, sql-server, vb.net, entity-framework

We make considerable use of Entity Framework in a database first model with entity framework 6 and SqlSever 2012.

We have a number of fairly long running processes (10's of seconds) which each create an object of the same type with different data these objects in their creation both write and delete data in the database using the entity framework. So far so good. In order to improve the performance of the application we are looking to runs these operations in parallel and as such are using the `Task` construct to achive this as follows:

```
Private Async Function LongRunningProcessAsync(data As SomeData) As Task(Of LongRunningProcessResult)
    Return Await Task.Factory.StartNew(Of LongRunningProcessResult)(Function()
                                                       Return Processor.DoWork(data)
                                                     End Function)             
End Function
```

we run 10 of  these and wait for them all to complete using `Task.WaitAll`

```
Class Processor
    Public Function DoWork(data As SomeData) As LongRunningProcessResult
        Using context as new dbContext() 
           ' lots of database calls 
           context.saveChanges()
        end Using

        ' call to sub which creates a new db context and does some stuff
        doOtherWork()

        ' final call to delete temporary database data
        using yetAnotherContext as new dbContext()
            Dim entity = yetAnotherContext.temporaryData.single(Function(t) t.id = me.Id)
            yetAnotherContext.temporaryDataA.removeAll(entity.temporaryDataA)
            yetAnotherContext.temporaryDataB.removeAll(entity.temporaryDataB)
            yetAnotherContext.temporaryData.remove(entity)

            ' dbUpdateExecption Thrown here
            yetAnotherContext.SaveChanges()
        end using
    End Function
End Class
```

this works well ~90% of the time the other 10% it deadlocks the database server with an inner deadlocking exception

all processors use the same tables but share absolutely no data between processes (and do not depend on the same FK rows) and create all their own entityframework contexts with no shared interaction between them.

reviewing profiling behavior of the `Sql Server` instance we see a large number of very short lived lock acquisitions and releases between each successful query. Leading up to a eventual deadlock chain:

```
Lock:Deadlock Chain Deadlock Chain SPID = 80 (e413fffd02c3)         
Lock:Deadlock Chain Deadlock Chain SPID = 73 (e413fffd02c3)     
Lock:Deadlock Chain Deadlock Chain SPID = 60 (6cb508d3484c)
```

The locks themselves are of type `KEY` and the deadlocking queries are all for the same table but with different keys of the form:

```
exec sp_executesql N'DELETE [dbo].[temporaryData]
WHERE ([Id] = @0)',N'@0 int',@0=123
```

We relatively new to the entity framework and are at a loss to identify the root cause of what appear to over-scoped locks (I'm unable to identify through sql profiler the exact rows being locked).

EDIT: [deadlock.xdl](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/c494a24c8005c5315a0e)

EDIT2: Calling `saveChanges` after each remove statement removes the deadlock still don't quite understand why it was deadlocking

Comment: Do you have an xdl file available? If so, check the transaction isolation level for each of the processes involved. I'd bet dollars to donuts that at least one of them is set to "serializable".

Comment: isolationlevel="read committed (2)" for all

Comment: Looks like I lost that bet. :) Are you able put the XDL file somewhere for analysis?

Comment: @BenThul see attached xdl cheers

Comment: Hmm… that's weird. Is it possible that different threads are a) trying to delete multiple singletons in one transaction and b) trying to delete the same IDs? Depending on your version of SQL Server, you can confirm or deny a) for sure and probably b) as well with extended events.

Comment: I've confirmed they are different ID's the delete action appears to be locking the whole table.

Comment: The deadlock graph says differently. Specifically, that the locks involved are key locks. You could put an extended event on a table lock acquisition though to confirm your suspicious, though. Another thing that would cause the deadlock is if you select a different ID within the same transaction as you're deleting. That is, if xact 1 does `select ID1; delete ID2;` and xact 2 does `select ID2; delete ID1` you'd get a deadlock if the timing was bad (which can be exacerbated by the either of the select or delete operations not being indexed well).

Comment: When you pull the data from the DB, you can use .AsNoTracking() if you're not going to change the data. This can reduce deadlocks as EF will not look at those entities. Don't know if that will fix your issue, but it might help.

Comment: There is a very interesting article explaining how to locate a deadlock with SQL Profiler, here : [How to track down deadlocks using sql server 2005 profiler](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/how-to-track-down-deadlocks-using-sql-server-2005-profiler/)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You appear to be the victim of *Lock Escalation*

To enhance performance, Sql Server (and all modern DB engines) will convert many low level fine grain locks into a few high level coarse grain locks. In your case, it goes from row level locks to a full table lock after the threshold is exceeded. You can resolve this a few different ways:

1. One solution is to call SaveChanges() which you have already done.
   That will release the lock sooner, preventing lock escalation from
   occurring, as lower lock count = less likely to hit the escalation
   threshold.
2. You could also change the isolation level to read uncommitted, which
   would lower the number of locks by allowing dirty reads, which would
   also prevent lock escalation from occurring.
3. Finally, you should be able to send an ALTER TABLE command using SET
   ( LOCK_ESCALATION = { AUTO | TABLE | DISABLE } ). However table
   level locks are still possible even when Disabled. MSDN points to
   the example of scanning a table with no clustered index under a
   serializable isolation level. See here:
   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190273(v=sql.110).aspx

In your case, the solution you have of calling save changes, resulting in the transaction being committed and the lock being released is the preferable option.

Answer (score 0):

A deadlock occurs when 2 (or more) processes want the same resources but each process acquires its resources in a different order. The (quite complicated) way to avoid this is to get the resources in a definite order. So, for example, when updating a bunch of records (of the same type) update the records in order of their primary key.

A simpler way is to nominate a root of your transaction - some parent record, and always update that first. So, if you segregate your tables into logical bits - DDD calls these Aggregates and have a single area of code responsible for updating each aggregate then the code for a particular aggregate can always update the root of the aggregate first before fiddling (now in any order you like) with the child tables in the aggregate.

In this way 2 or more operations on the same aggregate (say a Customer Aggregate with CustomerId 123) will both attempt to update Customer aggregate root. One will win and the other will be blocked (but not deadlocked) until the winner has commited its changes. This approach will also help you ensure that invariants in the aggregate are maintained and further more a version number/timestamp on the root will allow you to check for (otherwise hidden) updates.

EF may not help you here - you may have to update the root and save changes first to ensure that EF doesnt decide the order of your updates and put the root last - which would defeat the purpose.